# How to work with parameters?

Tags: modeling, dimensions

How can I work with parameters in Blender? I tried searching on Google, but I didn't find results.

When I change the parameter on the X and Y axis, it works well, but when I go into Edit mode, I can't see the parameters. And when I extrude, I can't adjust them on the extrusion. How can I work with dimensions and how to make the parameters in real world scale?

Comment: See also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/what-are-some-best-practices-when-modelling-with-exact-measurements/275#275

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68678/28015

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First set the *Units* in the Scene properties to *Metric* or *Imperial*. If you are using Imperial, then checking *Separate Units* can help make it more natural.

For 2.8x [image]

For 2.7x [image: Units]

When entering in units in Object mode using the *Dimensions*, watch the scale. You have to apply the scale ( <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale* ) before the same measurements will show in edit mode. When the scale of the object is applied (all three field set to 1)  then dimensions will work as excepted in edit mode. 
[image]

Comment: How do you have the "scale" transforms in edit mode?

Comment: And do I have to use the "scale" or "dimensions" for modeling?

Comment: @Vladimir there is no scale transform box in edit mode, that is one of the reason that the object must be scaled to 1.

Comment: Ok thanks. I meant about the two boxes in the panel - "scale" and "dimension", the second one should be used, right?

Comment: yes the dimensions are what you will be entering.

Comment: @Vladimir it's you https://www.google.com/#q=380cm+to+m

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16229/discussion-between-vladimir-and-david).

Comment: how can I scale individual faces in edit mode. I have the hight of the cube 2.4m and now one face needs to 3cm higher. In edit mode when I tipe 3 it scales in meters or something. Do you know how?

Answer (score 2):

First set your units in the properties window.

In **Edit Mode** you can use numeric input for transformations two ways:

Using **Transform** on the numeric tabs.

[image]

Or by inputting your parameters using the keyboard.

<kbd>S</kbd> to scale, <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate, <kbd>G</kbd> to grab (move),<kbd>E</kbd> to extrude.

For example: to extrude a face 2 units on the Z axis you'd select a face and type <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>

To scale something in half you'd type <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>

To double the size on the Y axis only you'd type <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>

To rotate 90 degrees in X you'd type <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

To move minus two units in X and Z you'd type <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>