# Real world to blender modeling

Tags: modeling, objects, units

I'm new to blender and I am trying to create basic shapes/models of few basic objects like - water pot, bottle, tea-cup etc. Now I'm trying to create an iPhone model.

So, when I started modelling, I came to know about precise sizing & other specific dimensions of iPhone. But I see options in XYZ as 0 & 1.
My Question is - How can I create an object with specifications like - 4 inch wide, 1 inch tall etc?

[image]

Comment: duplicate questions http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/254/2217, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14729/2217

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this can be done by changing the unit type from *none* to *imperial*
[image]

Then, add your cube and change the measurements to whatever you want 
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to change units? It is in inches" by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify measurements for newly created objects and other parameters in a pop-up window that appears by your cursor.
After starting the command and (very important) before starting another operation, press <kbd>F6</kbd>.
[image: F6 menu]
After setting the initial size of your mesh, you'll need to go into edit mode and use the mesh editing tools to make your object fit your other dimensions.
If you're from a CAD background, this can seem a little archaic-but in visualization, making something look right is more important than making it dimensionally accurate, so gauging things with your eyes is appropriate.

Comment: I was just trying to add to what you said