# How to set font size in points?

Tags: transforms, text-object, units

I am using Metric and want to type text to export as a STL for my 3D Printer. Is there a method of knowing or setting up the text size in points (pt)? In all other programs I select the size and know that I need a size of say 155, how can I do this in Blender? The scale I have as 1.000 if that's correct?

Comment: What units are the other programs using? (points?)

Comment: Yes, Points so I have 2 Different Text Sizes I use, 155pt and 255pt so I'm trying to do this in Blender.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to set the size of a text object in points.
A point is just another unit of measure ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29)), so if you know the size point that your other programs and printer are using then you can set the size in blender. Typically a point is 1/72 of a inch or 0.3515mm. So for your 155pt you could set the size to be 54.4825mm.

The quickest way to do so would be to first, [set the units to be Metric](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14731/2217).
Then in the Properties panel, <kbd>N</kbd> to show it. Type in `54.4825mm` to the Y axis. Copy the scale from the Y axis to the X and Z axes. The text is now sized at 155pt.
[image: Properties panel]

Comment: THANK YOU David, that really explained a lot, my only difference is I see Metres in the Y Dimension not cm like it shows in your image. At least I have something appearing when exporting it as an STL

Comment: @ken Blender will automatically change the units depending on how big the object is. So when you scale it down to the right size it will say cm. Plus you can type any units in there no matter what unit it is using.