# Font size (Text, Curve)

Tags: text-object, font

When adding a Text Object (or using the Python scripting API to create an Object from a Font Curve) with the "Bfont Regular" default font, for a capital oh ("O") that results in dimensions of (733,700,0) - why?
Is there a font size parameter in [Points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)) so that e.g. a setting of 12pt results in approx 4.2 mm letter height (apparently not quite that simple, see [em](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)))?

[How to set font size in points?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18115/how-to-set-font-size-in-points) does not explain it, but suggests scaling to obtain a required Point size.

- https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/texts/introduction.html
- https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/texts/properties.html#font
- https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/texts/properties.html#transform

> Size
> Controls the size of the whole text (no way to control each char size independently). Note however, that chars with different fonts
> (different styles, see below) might have different visible sizes.