# Faces look inverted like incorrect normals, but normals are fine. Please Help

Tags: modeling, normals, faces

The faces when I'm in Object/Edit mode look... messed up, like half of the normals are facing the wrong way. I checked the normals and they are all facing out like they should be. I was messing with some camera settings when I pulled out of the camera view. When I render the scene, everything looks normal. Let me know if you need more info on anything. Any help is much appreciated.

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I really don't know what to call this conundrum in order to search for it.

Uploaded: [Blend File](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=03781493883205645955)

[image: Faces Inverted]

Comment: Please upload your .blend.

Comment: Probably a non manifold mesh. In edit mode, try to find it, by using shift+ctrl+alt+M (yes the 4, or in the select menu, 'select all by trait' and 'non manifold'): this may select the concerned vertices

Comment: The view-camera's clipping has an exaggerate End clipping value. Large frustrums cause imprecision in the rendering. See, for example, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/shadows-along-edges-of-mesh-in-3d-view?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: [My answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23693/2217) should help explain why this is happening.

Comment: Yes! Haha, Carlo and David, both of these answers helped, I was just being an idiot with clipping regions with my camera, so this has solved my issue.

lemon, even though this wasn't the cause of the issue I had, I did find  part of my mesh which made it non-manifold. I didn't even realise it made issues not having everything corrected so I will be on the look out for that.

Thank you for everyone who helped me figure out my stupid mistake!