# How to fix inconsistent surface Normals of a shape in Blender?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, normals, subdivision-surface

I have a 3D shape whose surface Normals seem not to be consistent. It looks like the image below after rendering. It seems that the Normals are not consistent for this shape. I have tried `Solidify` and `Subdivision Surface` modifiers but they seem not to work (or I'm not setting their parameters correctly). I wonder how I can resolve this issue. Any help would be appreciated. [Here](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/n8okSAtNGeUAQ2iFslCJQNO8hfjzT0vR659OWhv6aLB) you can find the 3D shape.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this answer and see if it helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/89357/38953

Comment: looks like z-fighting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except from what @bertmoog has posted, your mesh has several more problems but you can easily and quickly clean it up.

[image: final]

1. Original imported mesh.
2. Select all parts then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join them.
3. In **Edit Mode** press <kbd>W</kbd> > **Remove Doubles** to remove doubled vertices, it will also remove marked sharp edges.
4. In **Object Mode** set **Shading** to **Smooth** and turn on **Auto Smooth** with default value.
5. Back in **Edit Mode**, select all and <kbd>P</kbd> > **By loose parts** to separate meshes to original state. You can skip this step if you will want to have it as one object.

Comment: thanks to blender's ever-changing user interface, this has changed much (you will now be welding verticies, or can even auto-weld (upper right corner button .//` looks like that, its right by options). Now they have confused the issue further by removing and adding items that do the same thing and have them "hidden" amongst the menu items like easter eggs. Take my advice, get the spacebar/f3 search menu and be done with it-everything in one place as it should be. Did you save your work recently? Do it now!