# Precision modeling - how to achieve this simple shape?

Tags: modeling

I know this is a basic question. I know how to model the shape below but I don't understand how, if I want to do it with precise measurements.

I started with a cube and set the dimensions but then how to do the diagonal face?

Can someone guide me on how to do this?

Thanks.[image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14729/how-to-work-with-parameters and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-to-model-effectively-using-exact-measurements

Answer (score 8):

To create a mitered corner like that, start with a cube.

Set the dimensions here:

[image]

[Apply scale](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data) type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>. This step is important [read this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#47320).

[image]

Enter edit mode.

On top Ortho abview select the top left vertices and move them 0.026m on the X axis. To make precise movements use the [numeric input](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/numeric_input.html?highlight=scale) features of blender: you can type directly the amount you want to move and in which axis, like this:

<kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>

(Meaning: grab/move 0.026m on the X axis)

[image]

Select now the vertices on the bottom right and Extrude 0.068m (or however much you need, since you omitted that measurement) on the Y axis

<kbd>E</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>

[image]

Switch the pivot point to Active Element, select one of the vertices on the left side to make it active and select the rest of the top vertices, and then scale to 0

<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

[image]

In order to see measurements on the 3D viewport in edit mode enable Mesh display->Edge Info->Length

[image]

Note that the units used will be those that have been set up on the scene-units section.

[image]

(form the [Blender Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/buttons_and_controls.html?highlight=units#units))

> ## Units
>
> You can mix units with numbers; for this to work, units need to be set in the scene settings (Metric or Imperial).
>
> Examples of valid units include:
>
> 1cm
>
> 1m 3mm
>
> 1m, 3mm
>
> 2ft
>
> 3ft/0.5km
>
> 2.2mm + 5' / 3" - 2yards
>
> Note that the commas are optional. Notice how you can mix between metric and imperial even though the display can only show one at a time.

Read on [unit names here](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/buttons_and_controls.html?highlight=units#unit-names)

Comment: Or when setting dimensions of basic cube add a loopcut for it, position it to 26 mm from the corner and extrude resulting face. Connect vertices in the corners and once ready, [dissolve edges directed under straight angle](http://i.imgur.com/S2FhEAX.jpg) (selected).

Comment: Thanks Mr Zak. It seems simple but there are some tricks for someone who is starting. That helped a lot!

Comment: Here i was thinking apply scale was only really helpful for developing games. Also it should be worth noting to set the measurements to cm go to the scene tab, and under Units click metric. (Or imperial, but that's not cm)