# How to calculate specific liquid volume?

Tags: fluid-simulation, units, measurement

I'm new to Blender and have a question regarding modeling of realistic scaled objects.
I'm modeling a complex shaped bottle and I would like to scale it (using metric values) to hold a specific volume of water.

More specifically:

- I know the volume of water - 0.5 liters.
- I have the bottle model.
- I want to know the realistic dimensions in millimeters of the bottle model that would hold 0.5 liters(it's diameter along it's height etc).

Doing this with a simple shape (e.g. cube or cylinder) is easy to calculate but for a more complex object it's not.

Also, is it possible to simulate flow of a specific quantity of liquid? In that way I could fill the model and in a few iterations have the right proportions.

Comment: There is an option in Blender for showing meter or imerial, go to the property->active scene-> and select unit you want, this may help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a cube, to scale it that it has a volume of 500ml, calculate the 3rd root of 500 ~ 7.93 (this should be the edge-length) scale the cube to this size.
For a bottle you might want to model a funnel.

For the fluid simulation setup:

- Set the cube as fluid
- The vessel as obstacle
- The funnel as obstacle

For all set the *Rigid Body Collisions shape* as Mesh.

- Add a domain object as domain
- Set the rigid body types to passive otherwise they will fall down.
- Increase the resolution to ~90 (more would be better but extremely time consuming)
- Bake the fluid sim.

[image]

After filling your vessel you can use the methods on exact measure as described here:
[How to model effectively using exact measurements?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-to-model-effectively-using-exact-measurements).

Instead of pasting all settings I uploaded the [.blend here](http://pasteall.org/blend/33129)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to measure the flow of the liquid.  If you place a cube of liquid above the bottle, that you could easily make the required volume, and 'pour' the liquid into the bottle using a funnel you could as you say perform this a few times and scale your bottle to the required size.  This assumes that blender preserves liquid volume during simulation.

There are mathematical models for calculating volume for complex shapes but without knowing more about your specific requirements I wouldn't suggest going to the effort of investigating them.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create an object such as a cube, and calculate the volume of that. Run a test simulation and have the cube pour into your container. The volume of the cube should be the volume of the water inside. Simply scale to fit your needs.