# How to model with precision

Tags: measurement

My 3D modeling skills are limited to SketchUp, so forgive my lack of experience. I don't understand how to model something, in programs like Blender, with precision when it comes to measurements. How can I make something exactly 1/4 inches thick, or extrude a face by 2.38 inches, or 25 mm?

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/what-are-some-best-practices-when-modelling-with-exact-measurements

Answer (score 4):

You can just enter an amount when some operator is called.

First you'll have to set your units:

[image]

Then, if you choose `Metric`, you can press, for instance, <kbd>E</kbd> (Extrude), and then press, for instance <kbd>2</kbd>, to extrude the selected vertices, and move then by 2 meters.

Comment: That is exactly right! Very handy feature in Blender! Note that in orthographic view you can pres Num + 1, 3, or 7 to get the different angles, with a grid to help free-hand drawing and modelling to scale.

Comment: You can also type eg 2cm, 2mm, 2km in many boxes instead of using decimals. Doesn't seem to work in the "transient header input" modes like during an extrude, sadly.

Comment: @StarWeaver, works during transform here (2.72 release)