# How to create a plane about such dimensions as the length of other edge?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, dimensions

How to create the square (plane) about such dimensions as the length of some  other edge from the scene?

[image: blender]

Comment: But how to extrude the edge if only was same lengths along the x axis as well as y?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-to-model-effectively-using-exact-measurements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to [model with precision](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-to-model-effectively-using-exact-measurements), and the first step in this kind of modeling will be to turn on *Edge Length* and / or *Face Area* options in *3D View* > <kbd>T</kbd> panel > **Mesh Display** rollout.

[image: mesh display options]

After duplicating the original edge there are several options to model square plane then.

#### Extrude with snapping

1. Turn on snapping with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and set it to *Increment*. Alternatively, without turning it on hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while extruding.
2. Extrude edge and see the values of the edges.

[image: Extruding with snap]

#### Duplicate and rotate original edge

1. Set the Pivot point to *Active Element*, duplicate original edge, rotate it by 90 degrees around appropriate axis (in this case Z).
2. Select all and press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove doubles* (because one appeared when you rotated the edge).
3. Select 2 vertices on the edges' ends and connect them with <kbd>F</kbd>. The triangle was created.
4. Subdivide the diagonal edge. Select the vertex which apeared after subdivisioun, turn on snapping, set it to *Vertex* and grab selected vertex to align it by X and Y axes with already existing vertices.

[image: GIF - duplicating and rotating edge to make square plane]

Read:

- [Showing measures in the viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/276/1245)
- [How to model effectively using exact measurements](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-to-model-effectively-using-exact-measurements) - related question.
- [Mesh Display panel - wiki](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/introduction.html#mesh-display)

Comment: Thank you. I think that the first method works only when we have "typical" dimensions of the edge that it is possible somehow to fit them to the grid (I have 0.1707 - values which appear at extrude don't correspond to this length). As for second - in the shown example origin of the object (edge) lies precisely in the middle of the square which later is being created. How to get it?

Comment: @user3224596 As for the first method it's quite easy to look at the length of the original edge (before extruding) with Edge length turned on, extrude and type those exact numbers to extrude out. Second - after extrusion is ready select all edges, press `Shift`+`S` > *Cursor to Selected*, go to Object mode and set origin to 3D Cursor.