# What's the easiest way to draw the outline of a floor plan in Blender?

Tags: geometry

This is so easy to do in other applications but very new to Blender and haven't been able to figure out the right words to search for to find this exact information.

If I needed to draw this plane only knowing the dimensions shown and the the angles are 25 degrees what's the best way to draw this?

[image]

Comment: Isn't complex at all. Just import it in case you already have it, otherwise you can enable some of the *Mesh Display* options of the 3d Viewport when extruding from a plane: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxguF.jpg or draw it in any CAD tool like [FreeCAD](https://www.freecadweb.org/) in the first place.

Comment: @brockman it may not be complex for you but it's more than just a square which makes it complex for someone who's maybe used blender 10 hours total. Mesh display options I know but extruding from a plane and getting precise lengths not so much. None of the tutorials I've come across helped.

Comment: @brockman I don't already have it I drew this one in another application to post with this question.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-to-model-effectively-using-exact-measurements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start by drawing the contour, and then fill the shape with triangles...

For the contour, you may start converting all your measurements into some decimal system, as it will be easier for inputing the distances.

### Steps

- Set viewport to *top view* (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>), and disable perspective if needed (<kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>)
- Create a plane. (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) then *-> Mesh -> Plane*
- Go into *edit mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), and merge all vertices *at center* (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>)
- Make sure you are in *Vertex Select* mode (<kbd>1</kbd>) and the [Pivot Point](http://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html) is set to *3D Cursor*
- Extrude the segments:

  - Press <kbd>E</kbd>, than the axis you want to extrude (i.e. <kbd>Y</kbd>), then the distance (i.e. `1.68`) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm
  - Keep repeating this step
- In case of the angled segments, before extruding:

  - Set cursor to the last vertex with *cursor to active* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)
  - Extrude the new segment (<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, `0.60`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
  - And rotate the desired amount (<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, `+/-25`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
  - Continue extruding as before
- In the last segment, just select both ends and join them (<kbd>F</kbd>)
- Select all segments and fill them (<kbd>F</kbd>)

Done!

Comment: Thank you very much you helped me answer so many things I'm struggling to learn about Blender. I made some edits where I had a hard time to make it clearer for others. Will mark as answer after edit is approved.

Comment: One thing I don't understand which might be terminology. Why would you "fill it with triangles"? Is that what the final fill command does or are you talking about subdividing the surface?

Comment: @KerdosMedia, the last command just fill the shape with a single ngon... but it all boils down to triangles in the end, a bit hidden to the user... Even quads and ngons are triangulated behind the scenes. Anyway, 'filling with triangles' is not the correct terminology... 'polygon triangulation' is a better term, thought perhaps still a bit too technic.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative (lazy) approach is to take the image into photoshop or something else of your choice and cut the shape out and save it as a PNG go convert said PNG online to SVG and import the SVG into Blender then convert the SVG shape to a mesh. XD lol I don't recommend this way but it technically would work :P