# Remove Parts of a Flat Plane

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to start my model with a basic flat plane to represent a floor.  It isn't a square room, there are alcoves and other things that make the room irregular.  I've been trying to work out how to create such a shape in Blender and nothing I'm searching online comes even close to showing me how to perform what really ought to be a pretty basic task.  Here is a sketch of what I'm trying to draw.

[image: Drawn sketch of floor plan]

The measurements are there because I need it to be fairly accurate as it's based on a real room where I need to place furniture etc.

I've started by creating a 2743x3625 plane in Blender, and I want to remove the two cutouts, one in the top-left, and the other skinny one on the left side wall.  I thought I could do this by creating two more planes of the appropriate sizes, positioning them and using the Boolean tool to subtract them from the main shape.  This doesn't seem to work however, even if I extrude them to 3D shapes and try that way.

I've also tried adding loop cuts, but I can't manipulate those accurately enough.  If I try to set a position, it does so relative to the middle of the plane where it starts.  Am I stuck with this method?

Is there some other/better way of doing this?  Ideally this shape would be a single plane, not a bunch of planes grafted together, but I don't know if this is possible like it is in other modellers.  Any help will be greatly appreciated... I'm pulling my hair out.

(Blender 2.79)

Comment: try to use knife cut with contraint angle on

Comment: Boolean opeartions won't work on flat planes due to precision errors as planes are infinitely thin and Boolean requires some volume. Subtracting cubes should work, though cubes ideally shouldn't stay on the same level (Z coordinate by default). Easiest way is to create a huge plane, enter Edit mode and with Knife tool cut some lines in it

Comment: I'm trying this now, but I have no control over how long the cut is.  Ideally I could snap it to an edge of an intersecting face (like the 3D boxes I made for the Boolean modifier) so I could use that as a guide.

Comment: Create the shape as a path in your favorite vector drawing program (inkscape, illustrator, etc). Save as SVG. Import the SVG into blender and scale to the size you need it. Convert the curve to mesh and build the house of your dreams. Also keep in mind that blender units=1 meter, so a side that is 36525 units is over three and a half kilometers... is your project that large?

Comment: No I write my measurements down in millimetres, but I either enter them as metres in Blender, or I specify the units as mm when I enter the values, which also works.

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-to-model-effectively-using-exact-measurements and go through these links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=floor+plan

Comment: Thank you so much for those links @cegaton.  Even though I've managed to do what I need, that method to use the extrude function at a vertex is precisely what I was looking for.  I'm glad it does exist in Blender, even if it wasn't where I expected to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I came up with the solution by myself, based on new info provided about Boolean modifiers not working on flat planes in answers to my OP.  Instead of trying to model a 2D shape and then extrude it to a 3D shape later, it occurred to me that I should just create the 3D shape in its entirety and then use the Boolean modifier as it's intended to cut out the alcoves from the room.  I created cubes in the dimensions of each alcove, then used snapping to position them relative to the appropriate corner (a fiddly process), then apply the operator.  This has achieved exactly what I wanted.

[image: Room with boolean modifier applied]

I guess that if I still wanted a 2D shape then I could have still modelled it as above, then deleted the edges/faces that make it 3D, leaving a flat face in the shape I wanted.