# Is there a way to enter a precise amount of length or width for the measuring tool in Blender?

Tags: modeling, edges, measurement

I'm specifically talking about the Measure tool with the protractor icon. I wanted to resize my mesh to a specific length, but I'm having to tediously move the anchor points on it which is time consuming and inefficient. For example I'm trying to get an even 700 centimeters, but I keep getting around 701.554 or 699.4567 etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to model effectively using exact measurements?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-to-model-effectively-using-exact-measurements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By displaying edge length in edit mode, you can view the edge length as you move a vertex. In 2.79 edge length can be enabled in the properties region <kbd>N</kbd> under [Mesh Display](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/mesh_display.html), while in 2.80 it is in the viewport overlay menu in the header.

When you are moving a vertex, hold <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> to slow down movement so that you can get the exact measurement you are after.

When you are trying to get the sum of multiple edges to equal a certain length, you can create a temporary edge and use [snapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html) to align your vertex to the "measuring" vertex. Constraining movement to a single axis can also make this easier.