# How can i set a line to be an exact measurement

Tags: mesh, scale, measurement

I want to make a floorplan with exact measurements but cant figure out how to do this

All I want to do is be able to type in say 10 feet and have the selected edge change to 10 feet

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-to-model-effectively-using-exact-measurements

Answer (score 1):

### Scenario 01

In **Object mode** just change Dimension. *Than Apply* Scale  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to bring scale factor to 1, then you can see edge length in edit mode as dimension. Think about Object as an universal container that can contains any data set. (If you go to Data Properties of selected object you can assign any data set to this object container.) By changing dimension you actually change just a scale factor for this container not data itself.

[image]

### Scenario 02

In **Edit mode** you can select edge, press <kbd>G</kbd> move <kbd>X</kbd> along axis and type number like a math.
Let say if you have side 2 m and you want 1 m, type <kbd>-</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

[image]

### Scenario 03

You can delete all vertices. Click with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (create vertex), press **<kbd>E</kbd> Extrude** along <kbd>X</kbd> axis and type number of specific distance. Than same for edge to extrude second dimension.

Comment: i changed the dimension to the ones i wanted but the ruler doesn't see it as that size

Comment: What do you mean by ruler, you can attach a screen to your Q via edit. BTW If you change dimension, you actually change scale factor in axis. Switching to edit mode measure looks weird for that. That is why I wrote "Apply Scale" to bring Scale back to 1 so the deformation in applied. You have to think about Object as Container that containes some object data. I will edit my A later to make it clear ...