# How to work with measurements

Tags: modeling, measurement

As per diagram i have model. I want to make the handle of 180mm as mark in red.

[image]

I have tried so far.

[image]

Any suggestion or help how it works.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-to-model-effectively-using-exact-measurements

Comment: @batFINGER did get help with the link. i want to make the handle 180mm how it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do a lot of modelling for 3D printing, my favorite method for getting dimensions exact is the following:

1. Make sure vertex auto-merge is off

[image: Step1]

2. Grab the verts you want to make precise and snap them to the vert you want as your "FROM" point "G -> hold CTRL to snap"

[image]

3. Then grab them and move them along the axis you with to move them "G -> Z" and type in your amount "180"

[image]

Be aware that this works well for high poly meshes, but low poly meshes will have different dimensions across the centre of a face compared to the edge between 2 faces

Comment: can you plz resend the above 180mm final file

Comment: @atek You can post modeling jobs over here: https://blenderartists.org/c/jobs/paid-work/53

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=rEzk5Vo4" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/rEzk5Vo4/)

Comment: Thanks for sending the file. I have notice the 180mm should be arc and its handle? You have just have should be only the angle of 180mm. Sorry little bit confuse

Comment: lol, I was simply showing you a technique of how to get precise dimensions in Blender. I thought that was the question...
Are you asking how to model the round outer shape?

Comment: You mean like this?

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=prYaR0ao" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/prYaR0ao/)

Comment: How to calculate the angle of arc ....You know the length of the handle and you know the radius (Wiki indicates: "Presently, Olympic plates of 10 kilograms or more are 450 millimetres in diameter." So just enter the radius and the arc length into the calculator you find here .... https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/arc-length#arc-length-formula  and use resulting angle in your screw modifier.

Comment: Thanks for the file at last what i was looking i found it.

Comment: 1 more question. As is mention to right they need 5, 10, 15, 20 to 25kg. How can i set the size for different weight.