# How to increase the size of the camera and point cloud - 3d tracking

Tags: tracking

I made 3D tracking, and imported it in Blender through maya.
Now I have a camera and a point cloud, which are very small. How to increase their size?

I tried parenting to empty (then scale this empty), but in this case, the camera immediately turns in the wrong direction.

How to change the scale of the camera and point cloud, without re-importing them again?

(I spent a long time with this scene and it is the only successful version of the 3D tracking, I am afraid that I will can not restore it, if I start from the beginning).

---

**Here is blender file.** http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35762

There have already set the scene (with this addon - http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?279329-Copy-Particles-to-Rigid-Bodies - thank TARDISMaker for link), in the middle of the scene there plain, and on it - a very small camera, point cloud, and a few cubes to test tracking.

Comment: The camera motion is baked to keyframes? If that's the case, your only option might be to change the scale property in the scene panel, or track the camera in Blender.

Comment: yes, keyframes, as I understand. The main reason for which I need to change the size of the camera is that the physics in a blender does not work well with very small objects. 

As I understand, there is no auto-tracking in a blender, and in my video is no markers, but the camera pans along the uneven ground with autumn leaves.

Comment: Yeah, I fully understand what your talking about. It's just hard panning the view with smallish objects. And the funny thing is, is that cycles depth of field works needs real world dimensions to function properly! I don't know of a way to scale keyframes, otherwise, I would say that's it. Blender can track footage without placed markers. As long as there are enough non moving points with enough contrast, you should be able to track it in Blender easily.

Comment: Is there any chance you could change the scale in Maya? If so, that might be your answer.

Comment: @TARDISMaker Thank you, good idea, but I've tried, I've combined the camera and cloud in the group (strl + g) and increases the size of group about 300 times, then like everything was ok, but I think because of that something moves wrong , tracking becomes bad. I will try with another video, and maybe try tracking in a blender.

What should I do in Blender, if I do the tracking, and the point that I'm following it goes beyond the borders of the frame?

Comment: Is it possible for you to add the fbx file to your question? Otherwise it's just guessing.

Comment: @poor Here is blender file. http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35762 There have already set the scene (with a this addon - http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?279329-Copy-Particles-to-Rigid-Bodies - thank TARDISMaker for link), in the middle of the scene there plain, and on it - a very small camera, point cloud, and a few cubes to test tracking.

Comment: The problem might actually be your import settings. I don't really use fbx, but you probably set the scale too low in your import settings. I remember when exporting for UE4, you need to set the scale to 100 to get the right scale when imported into UE4, so that's probably your problem. Try it out, if it works, I'll write an answer for you to accept.

Comment: I've selected pf_data and could scale it as I like, is there another issue?

Comment: @TARDISMaker, Oh, export 3D tracking in Blender - it's a long story) I used PFTreck, exported tracking to a file with the extension ".ma", to open it in Maya, then from maya exported file ".dae" (collada) for Blender) This is - the only way I know how to export 3D tracking in a blender. I tried to use .fbx, but after import to Blender camera was looking in wrong direction. Here is the lesson that helped me: https://vimeo.com/124183959 The only problem - after the import scene is very small.

Comment: @poor Wow, thank you! What is "pf_data"? - data from PFTrack?

The main problem is that the camera and the зщште cloud is very small (and physics in a blender does not work well with small objects), but if I increase the size of the scene in Maya, before export to Blender - tracking becomes bad, I do not know why.

I need to have a camera and a point cloud of normal size, and tracking the same as it was when they were small.

Comment: Check your outliner for an object name which contains "pf_data". I forgot the correct name. If this is selected you can easily scale the empties with the camera, right?

Comment: Correct name is: **panning_leaves_4_pf_data**, screen: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GoFc9.png

Comment: @poor Thank you very much! It worked! But I'm not sure yet, has tracking changed after increasing the size or not ... but i think everything should be ok, I will test it and write, if it works! Thanks again!

Comment: Should work, if not you could also set the units: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254/how-do-blender-units-and-meters-feet-or-yards-correlate